# How can I access a specific record in a Kinesis stream?

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

I have a Kinesis stream active and running, to which I wrote a producer and a consumer using KCL library.
Is there any possible way to access a specific record, with the use of sequence number and partition key?

Comment: What is your particular use-case?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem possible.

A shard is consumed via `GetRecords()`, which either starts at the beginning or continues from a previous call. There is no capability to "jump" to a record based on a sequence number.